# Magento ad variable in phtml

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

We have a file for one of our affiliates and want to call a static block in a phtml file.

It has to be in here:

```
$domain = "domain.com";
```

The domain.com has to be a variable and I think it would be best to give it a static block so I can put my own variable there. It is for a multistore so every storeview need to have it's own variable.

Let me know if someone knows how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

### If the required domain is the current store url

To use the domain name for the current url

```
$domain = Mage::getBaseUrl();
```

### If the required domain is different to the current store url

I would make this part of the system configuration.

#### Create a new module

`app/code/local/Vendor/Module/etc/config.xml`

```
<config>
    <modules>
        <Juno_ProductRegion>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </Juno_ProductRegion>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <helpers>
            <vendor_module>
                <class>Vendor_Module_Helper</class>
            </vendor_module>
        </helpers>
    </global>
</config>
```

`app/code/local/Vendor/Module/etc/system.xml`

```
<config>
    <tabs>
        <vendor translate="label" module="module">
            <label>Vendor</label>
        </vendor>
    </tabs>
    <sections>
        <vendor translate="label" module="module">
            <label>Module</label>
            <tab>vendor</tab>
            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
            <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
            <groups>
                <general translate="label">
                    <label>General</label>
                    <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                    <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                    <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                    <fields>
                        <affiliate_url translate="label">
                            <label>Affiliate URL</label>
                            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                            <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                        </affiliate_url>
                    </fields>
                </general>
            </groups>
        </vendor>
    </sections>
</config>
```

`app/code/local/Vendor/Module/etc/adminhtml.xml`

```
<config>
    <acl>
        <admin>
            <children>
                <system>
                    <children>
                        <config>
                            <children>
                                <vendor>
                                    <title>Vendor</title>
                                </vendor>
                            </children>
                        </config>
                    </children>
                </system>
            </children>
        </admin>
    </acl>
</config>
```

That would create a tab and section in System -> Configuration where you can enter the affiliate url for each store.

To fetch the affiliate url you would use

```
<?php echo Mage::getStoreConfig('vendor/general/affiliate_url'); ?>
```

Comment: Hi Adam, thanks for your reply. Yes it is the domain url. I only need it without http://www so just domain.com, so without any things in front, would that work with $domain = Mage::getBaseUrl();? Otherwise I will try to make the second option